# Perform calculation on one list depending on value of second list

Tags: python, numpy

I have several lists such as:

```
A = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

Each float value corresponds to an integer, in order.  The floats represent a category/label, so I will not need to perform calculations on those values.

I need to find the average of the integers corresponding to each category.  For example: 0.02 = 0.33, since 0 + 0 + 1 / 3 = 0.33 and 0.03 = 0.5, since 0 + 1 / 2 = 0.5.  The average for a category will never be 0.

Then, I need to replace the integer values in my list with those averages, so:

```
A = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

becomes

```
A = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.33,0.33,0.33,0.5,0.5,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75]
```

I've tried splitting the list into categories and integers, zipping the two together, iterating over them to gather all of the integer values for each category, and then calculating averages.  Unfortunately it quickly went over my head and I was not able to troubleshoot my multiple nested for loops and if statements.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is presented as such, then one pure Python way is:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip, chain

def float_int_avg(sequence):
    def _do_grouping(sequence):
        for k, g in groupby(izip(*izip(*[iter(A)] * (len(A) // 2))), lambda L: L[0]):
            vals = [el[1] for el in g]
            avg = sum(vals, 0.0) / len(vals)
            for i in xrange(len(vals)):
                yield k, avg
    return list(chain.from_iterable(izip(*_do_grouping(sequence))))

A = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
result = float_int_avg(A)
# [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
```

**Nicer approach:**

```
from itertools import groupby, izip, chain, repeat
from operator import itemgetter

def float_int_avg(sequence):
    floats, ints = A[:len(A) // 2], A[len(A) // 2:]
    def _group(sequence):
        for k, g in groupby(izip(floats, ints), itemgetter(0)):
            vals = [el[1] for el in g]
            yield repeat(sum(vals, 0.0)/len(vals), len(vals))
    return floats + list(chain.from_iterable(_group(sequence)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fancy index on np.array with [boolean masks](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/array_object.html#using-boolean-masks):

```
In [248]: a = np.array(A[:len(A)//2])

In [249]: b = np.array(A[len(A)//2:], dtype=float)

In [250]: for i in set(a):
     ...:     t=b[a==i]
     ...:     b[a==i]=sum(t)*1.0/len(t)
     ...: print b
[ 0.33333333  0.33333333  0.33333333  0.5         0.5         0.75        0.75
  0.75        0.75      ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I import the data from a csv file into lists.  I'll have to dig into the numpy documentation to understand what is going on here, but it looks very clean.

Comment: @foushad I thought you know numpy since you have the numpy tag on it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put that list into a NumPy array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray(A)
>>> a
array([ 0.02,  0.02,  0.02,  0.03,  0.03,  0.04,  0.04,  0.04,  0.04,
        1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ])
```

"Each float value corresponds to an integer, in order." We can split these up using [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
>>> labels, values = np.split(a, 2)
```

"I need to find the average of the integers corresponding to each category." This is a job for [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.mean.html):

```
>>> import scipy.ndimage
>>> avgs = scipy.ndimage.measurements.mean(values, labels, labels)
>>> avgs
array([ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,
        0.75      ,  0.75      ,  0.75      ,  0.75      ])
```

"Then, I need to replace the integer values in my list with those averages". It's easiest to assemble a new array using [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack((labels, avgs))
array([ 0.02      ,  0.02      ,  0.02      ,  0.03      ,  0.03      ,
        0.04      ,  0.04      ,  0.04      ,  0.04      ,  0.33333333,
        0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.75      ,
        0.75      ,  0.75      ,  0.75      ])
```

Putting all that together:

```
labels, values = np.split(np.asarray(A), 2)
avgs = scipy.ndimage.measurements.mean(values, labels, labels)
A = np.hstack((labels, avgs))
```